# How to compare two substrings which are stored in dictionary p?

Tags: python, dictionary

[image]

I am trying to create adjacency matrix based on comparing overlaps between the substrings of set A.If there is a overlap between the substrings,then I will store +1 in the matrix M else wont.I have already written a code utilizing sequence matcher to compare the strings,but I am getting the following error while trying to execute the code.

```
import numpy
import array
from difflib import SequenceMatcher as sm
##
###read the file
##f=open('spectrum.txt','r')
##s=f.readlines()
##a=str(s)

a='{ATG,TGG,TGC,GTG,GGC,GCA,GCG,CGT}'
p= dict(enumerate(a[1:-1].split(",")))
print p    
n= p.keys()[-1]
print p.keys()[1]

M=numpy.zeros([n,n],int)
print M
for i in range(0,n-1):
    for j in range(0,n-1):
        if i==j:
            pass
        elif sm(None,p.keys(i),p.keys(j))!=0:
            M[i,j]+=1
        else:
            pass
print M
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find common substring between two strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715688/find-common-substring-between-two-strings)

Comment: My query was more on i have already written a code utilizing sequence matcher to compare the strings but I think there is error on how the strings from the dictionary should be called.

Comment: I don't really get what you're saying, but if you're having an error that you expect us to help with, please post the full text of the error and the full traceback in your question (as text, not a screenshot).

Comment: I have added the screenshot.Will that be helpful to understand my query ?

Comment: **(as text, _not_ a screenshot)**

Comment: I can barely read the text in your screenshot but it looks like you are getting `TypeError: keys() takes no arguments (1 given)` which tells you exactly what is wrong. You are calling [`keys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) with an argument. It does not take one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your traceback tells you exactly what the problem is.  In this line:

```
elif sm(None,p.keys(i),p.keys(j))!=0:
```

You've passed `i` as an *argument* to `.keys`.  `keys` takes no arguments.  You *might* have meant to use `keys()[i]`, but realistically, if you're actually trying to access `.keys()[i]`, somewhere you should've used `items()` instead of `keys()` so you'd have access to 2-tuples of in the form `(key, value)` from your dictionary.

Comment: Ohhkk..Now,I got it.Yes,I have tried to modify it in my code.Thank you.