# How can I find similar substrings between two strings in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have two strings that contain similar (but not identical) substrings:

```
A = """Here is a test of a sentence with a few words in it. 
The rest of this sentence is different, though."""

B = """And here is a test of a sent;ence with a few wordz in it, 
as well. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs."""
```

How can I get the similar text between them, i.e. "Here is a test of a sentence with a few words in it" in A and "here is a test of a sent;ence with a few wordz in it" in B?

Edit: as far as I know, this isn't the same thing as calculating an edit distance. Sure, I can calculate an edit distance between "sentence" and "sent;ence", but that doesn't help me to identify the matching substrings.

Comment: What ideas do you have on this, and what have you tried?

Comment: Have you checked out [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) to see if it meets your use-case?

Comment: Start from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715688/find-common-substring-between-two-strings) and end up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17388213/4099593).

Comment: There is no easy way to achieve this. You need to write your algorithm. Split the string into list of words. Check for common sub-strings differing only by one intermediate words (or whatever your condition is).

Comment: Is it supposed to be `sent;ence` (in B and solution) and `wordz` (in B)? Or just a typo?

Comment: @jatinderjit That is the point of the analysis, I believe. If the sentences end up in a state where they are *almost* similar, you still want to find similarities to a "as-close-as-possible" match.

Comment: The general approach is to [tokenize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), then compare token streams. but this is a very broad problem.

Comment: You could also look at edit distance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Comment: I don't see how calculating edit distance is the same thing as finding similar substrings. Is the implication that I compare the edit distance between all the words in both strings? And when I have those distances, how can I find the matching substrings?

Comment: When you same "similar substrings" do you mean that words or characters are the smallest unit of similarity?

Comment: What criteria considers the substring to be equal? Also are you looking for the longest match or what exactly?

Comment: @intrepidhero, I guess words?

Comment: You need to add the criteria for what you consider a close enough match, if it is sequences of words that are the same with just one different word it is easy to simplify the problem by using the indexes of common words and finding the longest sequence with a break of just one index or less in the sequence. You could also apply a hamming distance on the words that break a sequence to get a closer match

Comment: Do the words have to be in the same order to match?

Comment: If your question is for solving some wildcard cases based on any exist algorithm calculating, I think the topic is duplicated. Because the problem scope is still same. And also, the description of this question is not clear.

Comment: @intrepidhero, yes, the words have to be in the same order, since the idea is to match basically the same strings.

Comment: @KirChou, My problem is not how to calculate a particular edit distance (there are plenty of guides for that), but for finding matching substrings in strings.

Comment: The linked answer does not relate to the question asked. This is much closer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715688/find-common-substring-between-two-strings

Comment: Edit distance is necessary, but not sufficient to answer the question. Use the edit distance to convert each word into a `set` of words within a distance of 1. You'll probably still have to do the brute-force comparison outlined in the sequence comparison answers above, but instead of checking equality, check for set intersection.