# Find the longest substring in two genomic sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, pattern-matching, substring

I have two sequences AAAAAAAAAGAAAAGAAGAAG, AAAGAAG.
The correct answer is AAGAAG.

But my code gives AA.

There will also be times when two strings will be in this order AAAGAAG, AAAAAAAAAGAAAAGAAGAAG.

Here is my code

```
`def longestSubstringFinder(string1, string2):
    string1=string1.strip()
    string2=string2.strip()
    answer = ""
    len1=len(string1)
    len2=len(string2)
    if int(len1)>1 and int(len2)>1:
        for i in range(1,len1,1):
            match = ""
            for j in range(len2):
                if len1>len2:
                    if i+j<len1 and (string1[i+j]==string2[i+j]):
                        match=str(match)+str(string2[i+j])
                        print(match)
                    else:
                        if len(match)>len(answer):
                            answer=match
                            match=""
                elif len2>len1:
                    if i+j<len2 and (string1[i+j]==string2[i+j]):
                        match=str(match)+str(string2[i+j])
                        print(match)
                    else:
                        if len(match)>len(answer):
                            answer=match
                            match=""
    return(answer)`
```

Comment: Please provide a working example that people can just copy to their editor.

Comment: Your 2nd string is actually part of the 1st string.. it ends 3 characters from the end of the first string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find common substring between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715688/find-common-substring-between-two-strings)

Comment: @Chris_Rands, it still returns the same error

Comment: @AK47, yes the loop is getting tripped before it gets to the end

Comment: @Vignesh see my answer

Answer (score 4):

Get all the substrings of both strings, find the intersection of both sets of substrings and then find the largest string in the intersection

```
def get_all_substrings(input_string):
  length = len(input_string)
  return [input_string[i:j+1] for i in range(length) for j in range(i,length)]

strA = 'AAAAAAAAAGAAAAGAAGAAG'
strB = 'AAAGAAG'

intersection = set(get_all_substrings(strA)).intersection(set(get_all_substrings(strB)))
print(max(intersection, key=len))
>> 'AAAGAAG'
```

Comment: this is short & smart :)

Comment: This is a nice use of set methods. To reduce the computational complexity, especially in light of one of the strings potentially being quite long, one might potentially make it into one string comparison function, with a  `maxlength = max(len(input_string1), len(input_string2))` limiting the maximum substring?

Answer (score 2):

A few weeks ago I've stumbled upon the `difflib` package in Python and it's perfect for this kind of job.

Here's a solution to your problem:

```
import difflib
matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher()

str1 = 'AGAGGAG'
str2 = 'AAAAAAAAAGAAAAGAAGAAG'
matcher.set_seq2(str2)
matcher.set_seq1(str1)

m = matcher.find_longest_match(0, len(str1), 0, len(str2))
print("Longest sequence of {} found in {}: {}".format(str1, str2, str1[m.a: m.a+m.size]))
# Longest sequence of AAAGAAG found in AAAAAAAAAGAAAAGAAGAAG: AAAGAAG
print(str2[:m.b]+'|'+str2[m.b:m.b+m.size]+'|'+str2[m.b+m.size:])
# AAAAAAAAAGA|AAAGAAG|AAG

str1 = 'AGAG'

matcher.set_seq1(str1)

m = matcher.find_longest_match(0, len(str1), 0, len(str2))
print("Longest sequence of {} found in {}: {}".format(str1, str2, str1[m.a: m.a+m.size]))
# Longest sequence of AGAG found in AAAAAAAAAGAAAAGAAGAAG: AGA
print(str2[:m.b]+'|'+str2[m.b:m.b+m.size]+'|'+str2[m.b+m.size:])
# AAAAAAAA|AGA|AAAGAAGAAG

str1 = 'XXX'

matcher.set_seq1(str1)

m = matcher.find_longest_match(0, len(str1), 0, len(str2))
print("Longest sequence of {} found in {}: {}".format(str1, str2, str1[m.a: m.a+m.size]))
# Longest sequence of XXX found in AAAAAAAAAGAAAAGAAGAAG: 
print(str2[:m.b]+'|'+str2[m.b:m.b+m.size]+'|'+str2[m.b+m.size:])
# ||AAAAAAAAAGAAAAGAAGAAG
```

The [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html) documentation [says](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.set_seqs):

> SequenceMatcher computes and caches detailed information about the
>   second sequence, so if you want to compare one sequence against many
>   sequences, use set_seq2() to set the commonly used sequence once and
>   call set_seq1() repeatedly, once for each of the other sequences.

And it's also very fast!

I've timed [@AK47](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4889267/ak47) great [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45919976/6879744) and it timed `10000 loops, best of 3: 85.2 µs per loop`

My solution timed `10000 loops, best of 3: 31.6 µs per loop`