# Detect implicit substring patterns in python

Tags: python

Given two words I want to identify the common parts of it.

For example given the two words `"technology learning TEL"` and `"learning TEL approach"` I want to identify the common terms `learning TEL`.

Another example, `lightweight web applications` and `software web applications`, common terms are `web applications`

My current code uses `in` as follows.

```
for item1 in mylist_1:
    for item2 in mylist_2:
        if item2 in item1:
            tmp_mylist1.append(item2)
            break

print(tmp_mylist1)
```

However, it fails to identify implicit word phrases as I have mentioned above in the example.

```
if "technology learning TEL" in "learning TEL approach":
    print("done")
else:
    print("no")
```

Hence, is there any fastest way of identifying these implicit common consecutive terms in python?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean - are you just trying to find common words in two sentences? To have a function like `common("aaa bbb ccc", "ddd aaa ccc") == ["aaa", "ccc"]`?

Comment: @Dunno that wouldn't work, because had the second example string of yours been `"ddd aaa bbb"` the OP wants the function to yield `"aaa bbb"`, not `"aaa", "bbb"`.

Comment: Please, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715688/find-common-substring-between-two-strings

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the problem is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)?

Comment: You want a suffix tree. The naive brute-force approach quickly crumbles on any non-toy input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It surely exists quicker way to do that, but since nobody yet replied here is a solution:

```
import itertools

def best_combination(string1, string2):
    '''
    Gives best words combinations within both strings
    '''
    words = string1.split()
    # All possible solutions for a case
    solutions = []

    # Loop to increment number of words combination to test
    for i in range(1, len(words) + 1):
        # get all possible combinations according to current number of words to test
        possibilities = list(itertools.combinations(words, i))

        # test all possiblities
        for possibility in possibilities:
            tested_string = ' '.join(possibility)

            # If it match, add it to solutions list
            if tested_string in string2:
                solutions.append(tested_string)

    # Best solution is the longest
    solutions.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    return solutions[0]


print(best_combination('technology learning TEL', 'learning TEL approach'))
print(best_combination('aaa bbb ccc', 'bbb ccc'))
print(best_combination('aaa bbb ccc', 'aaa bbb ccc'))
print(best_combination('aaa bbb ccc', 'ccc bbb'))
```

Output:

```
learning TEL
bbb ccc
aaa bbb ccc
bbb
```

---

[More about itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

---

**EDIT**

Same thing, less lines, more one-liners:

```
def best_combination(string1, string2):
    '''
    Gives best words combinations within both strings
    '''
    words = string1.split()
    solutions = []

    tests = sum([list(itertools.combinations(words, i)) for i in range(1, len(words) + 1)], [])
    for test in tests:
        if ' '.join(test) in string2:
            solutions.append(' '.join(test))
    solutions.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    return solutions[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this method and it worked:

```
def AnalyzeTwoExpr(expr1,  expr2): #Case sensitive
    commonExpr = []
    a = expr1.split(' ') #splits each expression into an array of words
    b = expr2.split(' ') #splits each expression into an array of words
    for word1 in a:
        for word2 in b:
            if(word1 == word2):
                commonExpr.append(word1)

return commonExpr
```

This method returns an array containing all the words that were included in both expressions. This method has 2 required arguments, 2 strings, which are the 2 expressions to analyze.

Also, have a not case sensitive method:

```
def AnalyzeTwoExpr(expr1,  expr2): #Not case sensitive
    commonExpr = []
    a = expr1.split(" ")
    b = expr2.split(" ")
    for word1 in a:
        for word2 in b:
            w1 = word1.lower()
            w2 = word2.lower()
            if(w1 == w2):
                commonExpr.append(w1)

return commonExpr
```

Hope this works for you.