# What's the best way to find the intersection between two strings?

Tags: python, string, performance, set

I need to find the intersection between two strings.
Assertions:

```python
assert intersect("test", "tes") == list("tes"), "Assertion 1"
assert intersect("test", "ta") == list("t"), "Assertion 2"
assert intersect("foo", "fo") == list("fo"), "Assertion 3"
assert intersect("foobar", "foo") == list("foo"), "Assertion 4"
```

I tried different implementations for the `intersect` function. `intersect` would receive 2 `str` parameters, `w` and `w2`

---

**List comprehension**. Iterate and look for occurrences in the second string.

```python
return [l for l in w if l in w2]
```

**Fail** assertion 1 and 2 because multiple *t* in `w` match the one *t* in `w2`

---

**Sets intersections.**

```python
return list(set(w).intersection(w2)
return list(set(w) & set(w2))
```

**Fails** assertion 3 and 4 because a set is a `collection of unique elements` and duplicated letters will be discarded.

---

**Iterate and count.**

```python
out = ""
for c in s1:
    if c in s2 and not c in out:
        out += c
return out
```

**Fails** because it also eliminates duplicates.

---

**difflib** ([Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html))

```python
letters_diff = difflib.ndiff(word, non_wildcards_letters)
letters_intersection = []

for l in letters_diff:
    letter_code, letter = l[:2], l[2:]
    if letter_code == "  ":
        letters_intersection.append(letter)

return letters_intersection
```

**Passes**

---

`difflib` works but can anybody think of a better, optimized approach?

**EDIT:**
The function would return a list of chars. The order doesn't really matter.

Comment: What's the expected output of `intersection('aba', 'aca')`? `['a']` or `['a', 'a']`? What about `intersection('ab', 'b')`? `[]` or `['b']`?

Comment: Are these just prefixes? If not, does the order actually matter or just the counts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find common substring between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715688/find-common-substring-between-two-strings)

Comment: @Aran-Fey `intersection('aba', 'aca')` should return `['a', 'a']` and `intersection('ab', 'b')` just `['b']` yes.

@ReutSharabani , edited the question. No the order doesn't matter.

Comment: what about `intersection('ab', 'abhab')`? `['ab', 'ab']`?

Comment: @xdze2 `intersection('ab', 'abhab')` would return `['ab']`

Comment: Just to make sure, but `intersection('ab', 'ba')` would be either `['a']` or `['b']`, correct?

Comment: @Aran-Fey `intersection('ab', 'ba')` would be either `['a', 'b']` or `['b', 'a']`

Comment: ok, so if I get it, also both `intersection('abac', 'abhac')` and  `intersection('acab', 'abhac')` will give `['ab', 'ac']`? the output is actually a set if the order doesn't matter, but then the output `['a', 'a']` is not possible... A counter `{'a':2}`?

Comment: Oh, so basically each string is treated as a multiset. That's easy, then.

Comment: Dupe: [Python list intersection with non unique items](//stackoverflow.com/q/12253361)

Comment: @Aran-Fey: but for every possible n-gram, not only individual char, no?

Comment: @xdze2 I don't think so. If that were the case, the output of `intersect("foo", "fo")` would be `['fo']` or `['f', 'o', 'fo']` rather than `['f', 'o']`, no?

Comment: @Aran-Fey: yes, so the output could be for example the sorted concatenation of the intersection of the counter of all individual chars. It is coherent with the proposed tests at the top of the question, but not with the following discussion in the comments... I think some clarification is needed

Comment: Please could you accept my answer if it works for you? (so that people in the future who encounter your problem will know which solution works for you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def intersect(string1, string2): 
    common = []
    for char in set(string1):
        common.extend(char * min(string1.count(char), string2.count(char)))

    return common
```

Note: It doesn't preserve the order (if I remember `set()` correctly, the letters will be returned in alphabetical order). But, as you say in your comments, order doesn't matter

Comment: @Aran-Fey Edited :)

Comment: `list(set(list(str1)))` can be just `list(set(str1))`. You have a typo in the `else` branch (`string` instead of `string2`). I'm pretty sure there's no reason to have the whole `if ... else` thing in the first place. And finally, repeatedly calling `str.count` on both strings needlessly increases your run time complexity. You can use `collections.Counter` to count all the characters just once. (And your code had syntax errors before the edit.)

Comment: `min(string1.count(char), str2.count(char))` <- that's a bug. You should be using `str1` there.

Comment: @Aran-Fey The if-else is needed to get the string of minimum length. I wouldn't need it if I knew for sure that the strings were of different length, but  as they *could* be, I'm using the if-else.

Comment: @Aran-Fey No that's correct. This is because the set() removes duplicates but I need to count duplicate characters when counting.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I've never used collections.Counter so I hope you'll understand if I'm not comfortable using it here :)

Comment: No, that's a bug. Try `intersect('abb', 'b')`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm on my phone right now so I can't try it. However, I know it should return ['b']. What *does* it return?

Comment: It returns `['b', 'b']`. I'll fix it for you if you don't mind. (If you do mind, roll back my edit.)

Comment: @Aran-Fey Nah, that's fine! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This works pretty well for your test cases:

```
def intersect(haystack, needle):
    while needle:
        pos = haystack.find(needle)
        if pos >= 0:
            return list(needle)
        needle = needle[:-1]
    return []
```

But, bear in mind that, all your test cases are longer then shorter, do not have an empty search term, an empty search space, or a non-match.

Comment: Unfortunately the test cases don't come anywhere close to covering all the requirements. If you read the comments below the question you should see that this doesn't do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Gives the number of co-occurrence for all n-grams in the two strings:

```
from collections import Counter

def all_ngrams(text):
    ngrams = ( text[i:i+n] for n in range(1, len(text)+1)
                           for i in range(len(text)-n+1) )
    return Counter(ngrams)

def intersection(string1, string2):
    count_1 = all_ngrams(string1)
    count_2 = all_ngrams(string2)
    return count_1 & count_2   # intersection:  min(c[x], d[x])

intersection('foo', 'f') # Counter({'f': 1})
intersection('foo', 'o') # Counter({'o': 1})
intersection('foobar', 'foo') # Counter({'f': 1, 'fo': 1, 'foo': 1, 'o': 2, 'oo': 1})
intersection('abhab', 'abab') # Counter({'a': 2, 'ab': 2, 'b': 2})
intersection('achab', 'abac') # Counter({'a': 2, 'ab': 1, 'ac': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1})
intersection('test', 'ates') # Counter({'e': 1, 'es': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'te': 1, 'tes': 1})
```