# Check if two strings has same words | Python

Tags: python

I am trying to find if two strings has same set of words for example if we have two strings like this,

```
a = "Linear Regression is a algorithm in ML"
b = "Linear Regression is a supervised learning algo"
```

I want my algorithm to find same set of words so I expect it to output **"Linear Regression"** as it comes in both the strings

I have tried this :

```
a = "Linear Regression is a algorithm in ML"
b = "Linear Regression in a supervised learning algo"

if a in b:
    print(True)

else:
    print(False)
```

It is returning `False`

That's why I want a algorithm which can do it efficiently and quickly.

Thanks!

Comment: You want the longest common prefix ?

Comment: If you want words, why it should not split Linear and Regression?

Comment: No this is not compulsory

Comment: @tevemadar Yeahh sorry

Comment: Why don’t you also expect “is a” in the result?

Comment: Do you want to find a list of the common words, or just a true/false whether the strings have *any* words in common?

Comment: This is known as Longest Common Substring problem and is described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715688/find-common-substring-between-two-strings

Comment: Thanks @JurajBublinec it solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this `list` comprehension with `str.split`:

```
print([i for i in a.split() if i in b.split()])
```

Output:

```
['Linear', 'Regression', 'is', 'a']
```