# How to get the intersection of two strings in this situation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have two strings:

```
str1 = "123147"
str2 =    "1474671231"
```

the end of `str1` has some similar part with the start of `str2` (`"147"`), and I want to find the length of this similar part, so I tried to:

```
for ch in str1:
    if ch == str2[0]:
        start_idx = len(str1) - date.index(ch)
        break
```

However the problem is it will return a mistake if the begin of `str1` is same as the begin of `str2` (`"1"`) and if I reverse the checking order, it still have this problem (`"7"`). Is there any simple method to solve it?

Most important, I only want to check the end of `str1` and the beginning of `str2`, and ignore other parts, for example, `"1231"` in `str1` and `str2` should be ignored.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find common substring between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715688/find-common-substring-between-two-strings)

Comment: Naively: run through the start index of the first string, from 0 to len(str1), take the substring str[index:] and check if the str2 starts with that substring. Does not start with 123147, not with 23147, not with 3147 but then you check 147 and it matches.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it didn't solve my problem because if the end of str2 have some same part as the end of str1, it will give a false answer

Comment: Using `SequenceMatcher` works perfectly for your example. Did you try that?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have tried this method in difflib, but still have some problem, please have a look on the most important part, thanks again:)

Comment: Do you mean that in your updated example the result should still be "147" and not "1231"?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem a problem to just try all suffixes of `str1`, starting with the longest:

```
def intersection_length(str1, str2):
    for i in range(max(0, len(str2) - len(str1), len(str1))):
        if str2.startswith(str1[i:]):
            return len(str1) - i
    return 0
```

Run as:

```
str1 = "12314755"
str2 = "14755467"
print(intersection_length(str1, str2))  # 5
```

Comment: Do you think it's possible to come up with a solution that is not O(n^2)?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. But it doesn't seem to be the question of the Asker.

Comment: Sure sure :) I was just trying to figure out how to do it

Comment: @Riccardo, you can take inspiration from the [Boyer–Moore string-search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to use a regex, and concat strings in a smart way:

```
import re

C = '#'
result = len(re.findall(r'^(\w*).*\1$', str2 + C + str1)[0])
```

The assumption here is that both `str1` and `str2` do not contain character `C`.

Another solution (which has optimal complexity, i.e. it's very fast compared to other approaches when you're dealing with long strings, but is clearly more complicated than what you need):

```
def longest_prefix_suffix(str1, str2):
    n = min(len(str1), len(str2))
    lps = [0] * n
    l = 0
    i = 1
    while i < n:
        if str1[i] == str2[l]:
            l += 1
            lps[i] = l
            i += 1
        else:
            if l != 0:
                l = lps[l - 1]
            else:
                lps[i] = 0
                i = i + 1
    return lps[n - 1]
```