# Compare strings, find part that is present in each string

Tags: python, nltk

How do I compare several rows and find words/combination of words that are present in each row? Using pure python, nltk or anything else.

```py
few_strings = ('this is foo bar', 'this is not a foo bar', 'some other foo bar here')
# some magic
result = 'foo bar'
```

Comment: I want a string that is present in each string. In the example above the result i need is "foo bar"

Comment: Is anything `structure` restriction - eg. cannot use certain `dict` or `list`?

Comment: nope, no restrictions

Comment: Hint - try to think about using `set` and looping over this strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the standard library `difflib` for sequence comparisons including finding common substrings:

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

list_of_str = ['this is foo bar', 'this is not a foo bar', 'some other foo bar here']

result = list_of_str[0]
for next_string in list_of_str:
    match = SequenceMatcher(None, result, next_string).find_longest_match()
    result = result[match.a:match.a + match.size]

# result be 'foo bar'
```

- The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.find_longest_match)
- The [two-string example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715688/find-common-substring-between-two-strings):

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

string1 = "apple pie available"
string2 = "come have some apple pies"

match = SequenceMatcher(None, string1, string2).find_longest_match()

print(match)  # -> Match(a=0, b=15, size=9)
print(string1[match.a:match.a + match.size])  # -> apple pie
print(string2[match.b:match.b + match.size])  # -> apple pie
```

Answer (score 3):

Split each string at whitespaces and save the resulting words into sets. Then, compute the intersection of the three sets:

```py
few_strings = ('this is foo bar', 'this is not a foo bar', 'some other foo bar here')
sets = [set(s.split()) for s in few_strings]
common_words = sets[0].intersection(*sets[1:])
print(common_words)
```

Output:

```
{'bar', 'foo'}
```

Comment: Nice. Spot on.  ~same thought..

Comment: and finally combine all items to make a string again to show the output

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin You can do that with `' '.join(common_words)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
few_strings = ('this is foo bar', 'this is not a foo bar', 'some other foo bar here')
```

1. Create sets of words for each sentence splitting by space (`" "`)
2. Add the first string to results
3. Loop over the sentences and update `result` variable with the interesction of the current result and one sentence

```
# 1.
sets = [set(s.split(" ")) for s in few_strings]
# 2.
result = sets[0]
# 3.
for i in range(len(sets)):
    result = result.intersection(sets[i])
```

Now you have a Python `Set` of words which occured in all sentences.
You can convert the set to list with:

```
result = list(result)
```

or to string with

```
result = " ".join(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using libraries too

```
few_strings = ('this is foo bar', 'some other foo bar here', 'this is not a foo bar')
strings = [s.split() for s in few_strings]
strings.sort(key=len)
print(strings)
result = ''

for word in strings[0]:
    count = 0
    for string in strings:
        if word not in string:
            break
        else:
            count += 1
    if count == len(strings):
        result += word + ' '

print(result)
```