# Is there a way to match to a key partially?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working with a set of key words and a dictionary in python and am looking to match the keywords with the keys in the dictionary but just partially.  For example if I have a key word like wide-plank floors I would like to match it to some key 'floor'.  Is there a way I can just check for partial?

Comment: Use a loop, iterate over the the key and use your own condition

Comment: take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715688/find-common-substring-between-two-strings. I think its in the spirit of what you are asking. you can set a minimum substring match to your key and the dictionary and return all keys that fit. This will be quite slow though

Comment: Dictionaries rely on an object hash, and one of the properties of a good hash is that even the smallest change to the object results in a completely different hash. A dictionary may be the wrong data structure for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a filtered dictionary:

```
dx = {k: v for k, v in original if "floor" in k}
```

Then you can assume the keys in `dx` all share the property of containing 'floor', and just work with the values. If you need to do something more complex, replace `if "floor" in k` with `if f(k)`, where `f()` is some function you write to decide if a key `k` should be included in the final set you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is there a way to match to a key partially?

Short answer: No.

Reason:

> [How Dictionaries Work in
> Python](https://medium.com/@faith.chikwekwe/how-dictionaries-work-in-python-162c6386c2cf)
>
> keys are “hashed.” Python dictionaries are implemented as a hash table
> behind the scenes. The dictionary uses each key’s hash function to
> change some of the key’s information into an integer known as a hash
> value.

So the only way to do a "partial search" (e.g. check the key against a "wildcard pattern") is to loop through each of the keys until you find a match.

Of course, once you find a matching key (by inspecting each key in turn), then you can use the dictionary to look up the corresponding value.

But you can't use the dictionary itself for a "wildcard lookup".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```py
for keyword in keyword_dict:
    if search_term in keyword:
        print(keyword_dict[keyword])
```