# bash longest common part of two string

Tags: bash

I have the following strings: "abcdefx", "zzdefghij"
I would like to extract the common part of the two strings, i.e. here "def".
I tried with sed but I couldn't do that unless the common part was a prefix like this:

```
fprint "%s\n%\n" | sed -e 'N;s:\(.*\).*\n\1.*:\1:'
```

Comment: This is not a trivial problem even using a real programming language.

Comment: What is the use case? This sounds like homework or idle curiosity.

Comment: I have files which I would like to classify following their base name into directories. The problem is that for one given base there could be files with some prefix separated with '-' or '\_' and zero, one, three, or four trailing substrings separated with '-', '\_', or even nothing. the only way to determine the base name for files of a given base is to extract the common part of the file names.

Comment: You might want to check out http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence -- some solutions for a similar problem in various languages.

Comment: (saying the obvious) ... and you have no opportunity to reorganize the generating system to create something that can be parsed more easily? Good luck.

Comment: A possible duplicate of [Longest common prefix of two strings in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973088/longest-common-prefix-of-two-strings-in-bash)

Answer (score 6):

This pure bash script will find the first longest substring of its two arguments, in a fairly efficient way:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ((${#1}>${#2})); then
   long=$1 short=$2
else
   long=$2 short=$1
fi

lshort=${#short}
score=0
for ((i=0;i<lshort-score;++i)); do
   for ((l=score+1;l<=lshort-i;++l)); do
      sub=${short:i:l}
      [[ $long != *$sub* ]] && break
      subfound=$sub score=$l
   done
done

if ((score)); then
   echo "$subfound"
fi
```

Demo (I called the script `banana`):

```
$ ./banana abcdefx zzdefghij
def
$ ./banana "I have the following strings: abcdefx, zzdefghij I would like to extract the common part of the two strings, i.e. here def." "I tried with sed but I couldn't do that unless the common part was a prefix like this"
 the common part
```

Comment: +1 superb... Had similar algorithm in mind but didn't get time to complete it.

Answer (score 4):

I thought this sounded interesting, here is my solution:

```bash
first="abcdefx"
second="zzdefghij"

for i in $(seq ${#first} -1 1); do
    for j in $(seq 0 $((${#first}-i))); do
        grep -q "${first:$j:$i}" <<< "$second" && match="${first:$j:$i}" && break 2
    done
done

echo "Longest common substring: ${match:-None found}"
```

Output:

```
Longest common substring: def
```