# Portable sed way to find longest common prefix of strings

Tags: sed

The `sed` solutions in [Longest common prefix of two strings in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973088/) only work with GNU `sed`. I'd like a more portable `sed` solution (e.g. for BSD/macOS `sed`, Busybox `sed`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solutions are tested with GNU sed, macOS (10.15) sed and busybox (v1.29) sed.

```
$ printf '%s\n' a ab abc | sed -e '$q;N;s/^\(.*\).*\n\1.*$/\1/;h;G;D'
a
$ printf '%s\n' a b c    | sed -e '$q;N;s/^\(.*\).*\n\1.*$/\1/;h;G;D'

$
```

To be more efficient when there are many strings especially when there's no common prefix at all (note the `..*` part which is different from the previous solution):

```
$ printf '%s\n' a ab abc | sed -ne :L -e '$p;N;s/^\(..*\).*\n\1.*/\1/;tL' -e q
a
$ printf '%s\n' a b c    | sed -ne :L -e '$p;N;s/^\(..*\).*\n\1.*/\1/;tL' -e q
$
```

---

#### Regarding `$q` in the first solution

According to GNU sed manual (`info sed`):

> - `N` command on the last line
>
>   Most versions of `sed` exit without printing anything when the `N` command is issued on the last line of a file.  `GNU sed` prints pattern space before exiting unless of course the `-n` command switch has been specified.

---

Note that I did not use `sed -E` because macOS' `sed -E` does not support `\N` back-reference in `s/pattern/replace/` command's *pattern* part.

- With GNU sed:

  ```
  $ echo foofoo | gsed -E 's/(foo)\1/bar/'
  bar
  ```
- With macOS sed:

  ```
  $ echo foofoo | sed  -E 's/(foo)\1/bar/'
  foofoo
  ```

---

#### UPDATE (2021-04-26):

Found this in another [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67121/29039) :

```
sed -e '1{h;d;}' -e 'G;s/\(.*\).*\n\1.*/\1/;h;$!d'
```

Note that it does not work when the input includes only one line. Can be easily fixed by removing the `1d` part:

```
sed -e '1h;G;s/^\(.*\).*\n\1.*/\1/;h;$!d'
```