# Why my range pattern is only working on the first file?

Tags: awk

I have a set of files (FILE1.txt, FILE2.txt ...) of the form:

```
foo 123
bar 456
start
foo 321
bar 654
```

And I want to ignore everything before `start` and only read lines containing `foo` in each file.

My attempt is this command :

```
awk '/start/,/EOF/ {if($1=="foo"){print $2}} ' FILE*.txt
```

And it actually works on the first file, that is it will print `foo 321` but then it will ignore the range pattern for the next files. That is, if we assume that all the files has the same content showed above, it will print:

```
$ awk '/start/,/EOF/ {if($1=="foo"){print $2}} ' FILE*.txt

321 // Expected from FILE1.txt, successfully ignore the first "foo" before "start".
123 // Unexpected from FILE2.txt
321 // Expected from FILE2.txt
123 // Unexpected from FILE3.txt
321 // Expected from FILE3.txt
...
```

What am I doing wrong ? How to make the range pattern working on each file and not only once over all the files?
I've actually found a workaround based on `find` but for the sake of a good understanding I'm looking toward a solution relying on `awk` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` processes all files as a single input stream. You need to tell `awk` when it's processing a new file and to reset it's pattern matching.

One approach:

```
awk '
FNR==1             { found=0 }          # FNR==1st record of new file, reset flag
/start/            { found=1 }          # found start of range, set flag
found && $1=="foo" { print $2 }         # if flag set and 1st field == "foo" then print 2nd field
' FILE?.txt
```

**NOTES:**

- `/start/` will match on the *string* `start` anywhere in the row, eg, it will match on `restart`, `last time I started the car`, etc; to match on the exact string you could use `$1=="start"`
- this was run against 3 files (`FILE{1..3}.txt`) that all have the same content as OP's sample input

This generates:

```
321
321
321
```

Comment: Thank you. However I don't understand why awk would evaluate /start/ many times in a single stream and /start/,/end/ only once. But actually it echoes what I've read here. WDYT ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk

Comment: your 'end of range' is based on finding the *string* `'EOF'` which does not exist anywhere in your input so the very first `'start'` found in the input stream tells `awk` to process the *rest of the input stream* with `{if($1=="foo"){print $2}}`

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong ?

`/EOF/` means line has three-letter substring `EOF`, it will not contact at last line of file unless that line contains substring `EOF`.

> How to make the range pattern working on each file and not only once
> over all the files?

I would exploit GNU `AWK` following way, let `file1.txt` content be

```
foo 123
bar 456
start
foo 321
bar 654
```

and `file2.txt` content be

```
foo 1230
bar 4560
start
foo 3210
bar 6540
```

and `file3.txt` content be

```
foo 12300
bar 45600
start
foo 32100
bar 65400
```

then

```
awk '/start/{f=1}f&&$1=="bar"{print}ENDFILE{f=0}' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

gives output

```
bar 654
bar 6540
bar 65400
```

Explanation: for line containing start I set `f` value to `1`, when f is non-zero and 1st column (`$1`) is `bar` I `print` that line, when I encounter end of file I set f to zero using [`ENDFILE` special parking](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Thank you A LOT, now I understand my mistake, I thought EOF was some kind of built-in variable or regex that I copy-pasted somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts [about row ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk) and [EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646633/how-to-detect-eof-in-awk).

One solution can be to set a helper variable.

```
$ awk -v row="start" -v regx="foo" '
    FNR == 1{x = 0}
    x == 1 && $1 ~ regx{print $2}
    $1 ~ row{x = 1}' file file file
321
321
321
```